# How do I access the error contents when using futures in Meteor?

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I am using futures to make an async call to balanced payments. I want to catch errors and feed them back to the user so I can tell them why their payment failed.

Here is what I get on the server console. How can I parse out the errors[0].status, or errors[0].category_code from this error? I've tried to simply `console.log(error[0].status);`, but this does nothing.

```
I20140616-14:38:59.169(0)?     "errors": [
I20140616-14:38:59.169(0)?         {
I20140616-14:38:59.170(0)?             "status": "Conflict",
I20140616-14:38:59.170(0)?             "category_code": "card-not-validated",
I20140616-14:38:59.170(0)?             "additional": null,
I20140616-14:38:59.170(0)?             "status_code": 409,
I20140616-14:38:59.171(0)?             "category_type": "logical",
I20140616-14:38:59.171(0)?             "extras": {},
I20140616-14:38:59.171(0)?             "request_id": "OHMf39d5030f56311e39cde02a
1fe53e539",
I20140616-14:38:59.171(0)?             "description": "Card cannot be validated.
 Your request id is OHMf39d5030f56311e39cde02a1fe53e539."
I20140616-14:38:59.172(0)?         }
I20140616-14:38:59.172(0)?     ]
```

Here is the future function I'm using.

```
var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");

  function extractFromPromise(promise) {
    var fut = new Future();
    promise.then(function (result) {
      fut["return"](result);
    }, function (error) {      
      fut["throw"](error);
      fut.return(error.message);
    });
    return fut.wait();
  }
```

I call this function from my code using something like this.

```
var customerData =  extractFromPromise(balanced.marketplace.customers.create({
        'name': customerInfo.fname + " " + customerInfo.lname,
        "address": {
          "city": customerInfo.city,
          "state": customerInfo.region,
          "line1": customerInfo.address_line1,
          "line2": customerInfo.address_line2,
          "postal_code": customerInfo.postal_code,
        },
        'email': customerInfo.email_address, 
        'phone': customerInfo.phone_number
        }));
```

Comment: You probably meant `errors[0]` and not `error[0]`, right? Could you also provide the `future` code which you're using here?

Comment: I did mean error[0]. I posted the code above, I hope that helps explain. I also tried error.errors[0] and errors[0], I get nothing from any of these.

Comment: What is the code that generated that `"errors": [...]` log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some help and got the answer. Hope this helps others. Here is the rewrite of the code I initially wrote.

The future code was both returning and throwing the error, so that was removed, the code was cleaned up a bit as well.

```
var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");

  function extractFromPromise(promise) {
    var fut = new Future();
    promise.then(function (result) {
       fut.return(result);
     }, function (error) { 
       console.log(error);      
       fut.throw(error);
    });
    return fut.wait();
  }
```

And then the whole thing is wrapped in a try catch. I console log out the different parts of the message. Turned out that the JSON was stringified, so that had to be parsed first, then I could access the error like normal JSON data. And I've just learned that no errors will get back to the client unless you use the `Meteor.error` syntax first.

```
var customerData;

      try {
        customerData =  extractFromPromise(balanced.marketplace.customers.create({
        'name': customerInfo.fname + " " + customerInfo.lname,
        "address": {
          "city": customerInfo.city,
          "state": customerInfo.region,
          "line1": customerInfo.address_line1,
          "line2": customerInfo.address_line2,
          "postal_code": customerInfo.postal_code,
        },
        'email': customerInfo.email_address, 
        'phone': customerInfo.phone_number
        }));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(e.message).errors[0].extras);  
      console.log(JSON.parse(e.message).errors[0].category_code);            
      var error = JSON.parse(e.message).errors[0]; 
      throw new Meteor.Error(error.category_code, error.status_code, error.description, error.extras);
    }
```